# General solution of $x^{\prime} = -x^{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand how to function to the general solution of this equation, or else this system of ode

$$\dot{x} = -x^{2}, \quad \dot{y} = -y$$

Clearly the problem is how to define the solution of the variable x, since there is the direct solution by separation of variables but there is also the null solution.

Now, my question is **How do you decide which solution to use?**

I imagine that they will tell me about the initial condition but I would like to know if there is a way to define the function based on the interval of the initial conditions.

Comment: the reason for using the system is because I am studying the saddle node bifurcation when the parameter is zero

Comment: $$\left(\frac 1{x}\right)'=-\frac{x'}{x^2}=1$$

Comment: @Moo 
it is because in some cases in the first equation one has the null solution but there is also the solution from integrating, what I am trying to understand is when using which

Comment: Ok, but for $x$ the initial condition  $x(0) = 0$ that solution is not valid, i.e, the other solution is $x(t) =0$, my question is when used which

Comment: It  depends on the initial conditions of the system @StrinoX3

Comment: @user577215664 
but how should be the initial condition to make that decision of solution?

Comment: For $x(0)\ne 0 $ the null solution is not a solution but for $x(0)=0$   the null solution  is  the correct solution @StrinoX3

Comment: Then write the solution as $x(t)=\dfrac{x_0}{1+x_0·t}$, this gives all the solutions with a finite value at $t=0$.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers i think i can work with that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simple and was answered in the comments.